# Why do my Github pages refresh to old version when I press refresh?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, github, github-pages

I am using Angular for my site http://3lfisticated.ga/ which is a Github page project page. Here is the repo all my code is at:

https://github.com/siddhion/3lfisticated/tree/gh-pages

When I click reload in Chrome or Firefox while at http://3lfisticated.ga/ the page will reload fine but if I click reload while on http://3lfisticated.ga/design or http://3lfisticated.ga/design/3lf the page will not reload correctly. Actually the page will reload an older version of the **index.html**. I know this because the footer links are not the same as the newer version.

I thought maybe doing a Hard Reload or Empty Cache & Hard Reload in Chrome would fix the issue but it did not. Also I should mention I never used Firefox to go on that site. So this is an issue with the code. Any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happened is because for some reason my **404.html** was being accessed instead of my **index.html**. The reason I did not catch this from the get go is because those two files were identical and I assumed that my **index.html** was always being loaded. Finally when I updated the old and unchanged **404.html** everything was normal.

I know my **404.html** should not be loading instead of my **index.html**.  Not sure why that is happening. I just needed a quick fix.